# The power of irrationality: ${\rm sin}(x) + {\rm sin}(\pi x)$

Tags: irrational-numbers

I'm a physicist studying undulatory phenomena. Reducing the problem, I find the issue lies on the relative irrationality of the angular frequencies of two superimposed waves. To state it simply, consider the function,

$$f(t) = {\rm sin}(t) + {\rm sin}(\pi \, t),$$

where I take the angular frequencies of the first and second "waves" to be $1$ and $\pi$ respectively, as their ratio is an irrational number, but the issue should arise with any two superimposed waves having an irrational ratio of angular frequencies. The phase $\phi$ of each wave is bound by a full period, as usual.

I understand that, due to the inherent irrationality, and since phase evolution is linear, the system never repeats itself, and thus each phase configuration $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ shall occur exaclty once for finite $t$. That is, all possible phase configurations $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ must occur at some finite time $t$, which, as far as I understand, refers to the *universality* phenomenon (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

So, I have three questions:

1. Is there is a closed-form formula for finding all the zeros of $f(x)$? Or, if there isn't, is there is a way for finding all zeros of $f(x)$ without having to search them one-by-one by resorting to minimization/zero-finding procedures?
2. Can we ever hope to find the time $t = t_2$ for which $f(t_2) = 2$, exactly? As far as I understand, $t_2$ could be an arbitrarily large number, can we ever prove a candidate $t$ to be the true $t_2$?
3. In general, given a particular configuration $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$, can we find -- by any means -- the time $t$ at which it occurs? In other words, the phases $\phi$ can be trivially calculated for a given $t$, but can we invert the relation to find $t$ as a function of given $\phi$'s?

**Edit**: I understand now I've been wrong about the system going through all possible configurations, and in fact the vast majority of the configurations is inaccessible for the system (see comments below), so question (2) is unfounded. According to directions provided, I moved the remaining question (3) in a reformulated version to the [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com) site:

[Can y=αx be solved for α irrational if the integer parts of x and y are unknowns?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241578/can-y-alpha-x-be-solved-for-alpha-irrational-if-the-integer-parts-of-x)

Comment: What does "the phase $\phi$ of each wave is bound by a full period" mean?  Also, what is a phase configuration $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$?  Are you ignoring the actual function $t \mapsto f(t)$ and just looking at $(\phi_1, \phi_2) = (t, \pi t)$?

Comment: @LSpice, I guess its a physicist thing, to be more precise, for a "wave" ${\rm sin} (\omega t)$, the phase is $\phi = \omega t \, {\rm mod} \, 2 \pi$. I'm concerned with both the overall wave $f(t)$, and the individual waves $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$.

Comment: It's not true that every phase configuration exactly once, you only know it can occur *at most* once. In particular, the two sines never take value $1$ simultaneously: if $\sin t=\sin\pi t=1$, then both $t,\pi t$ should be rational multiples of $\pi$, which can't happen for $t\neq 0$ as $\pi$ is irrational. For question $1$, you can use $\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}$.

Comment: @LSpice, by a phase configuration $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ I mean a cartesian pair formed by real numbers $\in [0,2 \pi)$.

Comment: @Wojowu, I'm aware of the sum of sines formula, but in question 1 I asked for a closed-from formula, or a way that doesn't require an interative procedure to find zeros one-by-one, I don't see how the sum of sines help there.

Comment: @Wojowu, sorry, I don't follow, could you please elaborate the argument why ${\rm sin}(t) = {\rm sin}( \pi \, t) = 1$ can never happen?

Comment: Let $x=t,y=\pi t$ in the above formula. Then $f(t)$ vanishes if either $\sin\frac{x+y}{2}=0$ or $\cos\frac{x-y}{2}=0$. The former happens iff $\frac{x+y}{2}=k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, which you can solve for $t$. Something similar happens for $\cos$.

Comment: $\sin x=1$ iff $x=\pi(2k+\frac{1}{2})$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. Hence if $\sin t=\sin \pi t=1$, then both $\pi t$ and $t$ are of the form $\pi\cdot$rational. But this would imply that their ratio, which is $\pi$, is rational.

Comment: The vast majority of configurations cannot occur: for any given $\phi_1$, there are only countably many $\phi_2$ such that $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ occurs, out of the uncountably many elements of $[0,2\pi)$. Also, the set of configurations that occur has measure $0$.

Comment: You have asked in the wrong forum.  Perhaps more appropriate at https://math.stackexchange.com ... but of course read the information there about what is appropriate for questions.

Comment: Ok, perhaps a more relevant question would be: knowing that a configuration $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ occurs, how to find $t$ when it occurs. But thanks anyway for the comments @Wojowu and Emil, they were indeed helpful.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, I restated the third question there: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241578/can-y-alpha-x-be-solved-for-alpha-irrational-if-the-integer-parts-of-x)

Comment: @Wojowu, thanks for the answers, I restated the third question in a simpler manner: [Can y=αx be solved for α irrational if the integer parts of x and y are unknowns?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241578/can-y-alpha-x-be-solved-for-alpha-irrational-if-the-integer-parts-of-x)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thanks for the answer, it added a great deal for my understanding of the problem, please note I restated the third question in a simpler manner: [Can y=αx be solved for α irrational if the integer parts of x and y are unknowns?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241578/can-y-alpha-x-be-solved-for-alpha-irrational-if-the-integer-parts-of-x)